# QtCreator can't find headers for files in add_custom_target

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I have a CMake project that builds fine in QtCreator (4.1.0). If I add my headers to an `add_executable`, all is well:

```
Project(AutoComplete)

include_directories(/home/doria/build/HDR-EXT/Install/include/eigen3)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(AutoComplete AutoCompleteDemo.cpp AutoComplete.h)
```

That is, the project builds fine, and both in `AutoCompleteDemo.cpp` and `AutoComplete.h` the headers are all found by the parser so autocomplete works. However, if I do this:

```
Project(AutoComplete)

include_directories(/home/doria/build/HDR-EXT/Install/include/eigen3)

add_custom_target(AutoCompleteHeaders SOURCES AutoComplete.h)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(AutoComplete AutoCompleteDemo.cpp)
```

the project still builds fine, the headers are still found correctly in `AutoComplete.h`, but the headers are NOT found in `AutoCompleteDemo.cpp`.

Below are the two test files:

**AutoComplete.h**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense> // this is underlined in yellow in the add_custom_target version
```

**AutoCompleteDemo.cpp**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the files in the `add_custom_target` to find the headers.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @usr1234567 It works as expected in a small project. I'm not sure what to change to make it more like my large project, so I guess I was looking for ideas of what to poke that might affect something like this.

Comment: @usr1234567 I found the real source of the problem - please see the updated question

Comment: And what is the "real source"? How do you make QtCreator show headers as normal includes (not underlined as "File not found"). I see no clear hint to that in the question.

Comment: @AndreyRogozhnikov It's that the files specified in `add_custom_target` do not behave correctly, while the files specified in an `add_executable` (or `add_library`) do work correctly.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the Pointcloud library (PCL) headers not being correctly looked up in my own header files QTCreator if I used `add_custom_target`. I was able to resolve the issue by applying [this IDE support tool](https://github.com/sauter-hq/cmake-ide-support) instead.